Jenkins multi-branch pipelines hurting the master node
When development is working hard, the multi-branch CI pipelines are kicking off fairly often.  In order to get the jenkins file for each job from source control, the pipeline is creating a small anonymous workspace on the master node and then building the branch jobs from that jenkins file.  All that thrashing to get the jobs launched is causing the executors on the master node to queue up.
My initial idea is to set the number of executors to 0 on the master node.  Will this allow Jenkins to do this first initial step of the multi-branch pipeline and check out the pipeline script from source control?  Where would the work get done since there is no place to define a node other than master in the definition of a multi-branch pipeline?
To be clear, once the branch jobs are created, they launch on the nodes they are supposed to launch on.  THAT is working fine.  It's the initial beginning steps of the CI job which are queueing as far as we can see.

You don't need executors (the normal, heavy weight ones) on your controller to get the pipeline code from the scm. That is done by flyweight executors that you cannot control. And if they are forced to do a full checkout that can create some congestion. Look into lightweight checkout - it's enabled by a checkbox at the bottom of your job config.
